Flutter: An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width
I am trying to get rid of the error "An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width."
It is strange because the TextFormField Elements are already wrapped by Expanded. I am really struggling with flutter layouts. I find it not always logcial and the debug notes are also no big help :(
What else could I try?
Please find below my Widget:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Stack(children: [
        const RouteList(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(mainPadding),
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _start,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.start),
                      suffixIcon: _ClearButton(controller: _start),
                      labelText: 'Start',
                      helperText: 'Enter your start location',
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      return _validateInpute(value!);
                    },
                  )),
                  divider,
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _destination,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.forest),
                      suffixIcon: _ClearButton(controller: _destination),
                      labelText: 'Destination',
                      helperText: 'Enter your destination',
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      return (value == null || value.isEmpty)
                          ? 'Mandatory field'
                          : null;
                    },
                  )),
                  divider,
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _submitForm(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
        )
      ]);
    });
  }


you should follow the best practice mean wrap you whole content in a container or sizedbox with defined width,
to use dynamic width you can use
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (padding * 2);

for example for your case you can achive this soimething like this
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final double mainPadding = 16.0;
  final double containerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - (mainPadding * 2);

  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          const RouteList(),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(mainPadding),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: containerWidth,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _start,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.start),
                        suffixIcon: _ClearButton(controller: _start),
                        labelText: 'Start',
                        helperText: 'Enter your start location',
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        return _validateInpute(value!);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Container(
                    width: containerWidth,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _destination,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.forest),
                        suffixIcon: _ClearButton(controller: _destination),
                        labelText: 'Destination',
                        helperText: 'Enter your destination',
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        return (value == null || value.isEmpty)
                            ? 'Mandatory field'
                            : null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _submitForm(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}

it will also help to handle ScrollViews and much more widgets
hope it will community

thanks, it works perfectly well. But i still struggle to understand the logic behind it.

buddy expand works like we are saying to an widget to take all space after the prev. one
so here we need to define some limit mean how much all :)
same goes with scrollview
i think there should be some limit to abstract user to use sizedBox or Container with Image
as limits while add widget in App Bar Bottom to use "PreferredSize"
